# Make SAPUI5 app work on outdated Fiori Launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I have a SAPUI5 Chart Application that is deployed onto HCP and added to a FIORI Launchpad site. The App uses certain components from a later version of SAPUI5 library (**1.40.10**) while the Fiori Launchpad is currently at **1.38.10**. When I run the app standalone from HCP cockpit, all the components work fine but as soon as I run the app from inside the FIORI Launchpad, the components fail since they don't exist in version 1.38.10.

What is the best way to make my app work in the FIORI launchpad without upgrading the SAPUI5 version.

Can I give preference to the version that I have declared in my **neoApp.json**  file as below:

```js
"routes": [{
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "version": "1.40.10",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
```

I found the below in the documentation.
[image]

But I don't understand how to implement this in my neoApp.json. how to set the SAPUI5 version to 1.40.xx in neoApp.json.

NOTE: I need to make the same application work in both SAP FIORI Launchpad and SAP Portal freeStyle Site (both of which are running SAPUI5 v1.38.10). Since both these sites are created from HCP, portal service, if it works in one, it would inherently work on the other. Please highlight  in case any additional steps are required to run it on the portal.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at:
[Configuring Site Settings](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/cloud_portal/frameset.htm?cb10beafb67c4ba09c13a3e6a9094b6d.html)

Here you can select a specific SAPUI5 version to use for the runtime.
The specified version will be used for all apps in this Launchpad site.
As long as no deprecated features are used, it should be ok with other (“older”) apps also.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that a SAPUI5 Application can override that and use a different version?

Comment: The SAP Fiori launchpad cannot use different UI5 versions for different apps.

As a workaround you might create a tile, which starts a new window, and from there, start the app standalone.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reach the internet you can try to load the correct version through the CDN from SAP Server by supplying its full path instead. Maybe that works for your scenario

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.60.13/#/topic/2d3eb2f322ea4a82983c1c62a33ec4ae

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    type="text/javascript"
    src="**https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.42.6/resources/sap-ui-core.js**"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
```